# Beamer: How to change the default color of covered text?

Tags: beamer, color, overlays

When I write:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> a b c
    \item<2-> d e f
\end{itemize}
```

in slide 1, the second item "d e f" is shown in grey. I want it to be white. Is there a way to make this behavior default for the entire presentation?

[Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations#The_do_it_yourself_solution) there are many examples for the \setbeamercolor command, but, I did not find any example relevant for changing only the color of covered text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the instruction

```
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
```

is somewhere in your document's preamble, along with (I would hope) `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}`. Change the instruction to

```
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
```

to make the covered items, well, invisible.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\mode<presentation>
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->} % optional but handy
\setbeamercovered{invisible} % or: 'transparent', 'dynamic', ...

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item a b c
    \item d e f
    \item g h i
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```